# Can you help me with data visualization?

Tags: diagramming

I have a problem and I can't find a solution. Maybe someone can give me advice.

I'm designing a huge presentation, which has many charts and I have problems with one. I want it to be logical and simple to understand for the client. But I can't find best way to do that. I can show a simple example of concrete situation, but this is not an option, because I want to show a basic idea for every possible situation.

Right now I have a table:

[image: Table with 4 columns and 3 rows. Shows values Apple and Cucumber with options Included in Basket, Red and Green]

The problem is that value can be included in basket, or not and can be green,  red, or both.

If there were only red & green, then I could use a Venn diagram, as some red, some green, some both. But how do I show that some can be also included and not?

The idea is simple for me, because I know what I'm doing, but clients may not understand. And because presentation is huge, idea should be clear.
Does anyone have a better idea of how to present the data?

Comment: You can still use a Venn diagram with three circles, nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work for colors... iconography for other values may or may not work.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH52Ie.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: This won't work for colorblind people. Also, I seriously suspect that this isn't really about colors.

Answer (score 0):

Why not adapt your Venn diagram solution a little bit? The circles represent categories, and the line represents the dichotomy. (You could of course simply use a third circle - but that has a slightly different feel.)

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhi8kf.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>